# PHP foreach /w key+value pairs over part of multi dimensional array

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to access data from a multidimensional array. Array `$o` contains arrays of with the key: product_id. The child array 'data' contains `key => value pairs` (or at least I think it does). The problems is that when I try to access the data later on: nothing is working.

**Question:** How can I access this data as expected in a `key => value` pair method that works (like `foreach($o[$_product_id]['data'] as $_attr => $_value)`)

Original data

```
$_product_id=1;
$h = array('header1','header2','header3');
$line= array(1,2,3);
$o[$_product_id]['data'] = array_combine($h,array_map('trim', $line));
```

I var_dumped `$o[$_product_id]['data']` and I can see the data is there

```
$data =
array (
  'header1' => 1,
  'header2' => 2,
  'header3' => 3,
);
```

Help appreciated

=======================

Loading data original method

```
$o[$_product_id]['data'] = array_combine($h,array_map('trim', $line));
```

Loading data alternative method

```
foreach ($h as $_atr) {
  $o[$_product_id]['data'][$_atr] = trim(array_shift($line));
}
```

Accessing data: not working as expected

```
foreach($o[$_product_id]['data'] as $_attr => $_value)
  echo $_attr;
  echo $_value;
```

Comment: You wrote so much words, but we didn;t see the original array.

Comment: Haha well was trying to be clear. H and LINE are the original arrays merged to key value pairs using combine

Comment: What do you mean by `not working as expected`?

Comment: I get attr attr attr val instead of attr val attr Val attr Val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, your problem is that your code:

```
foreach($o[$_product_id]['data'] as $_attr => $_value)
  echo $_attr;
  echo $_value;
```

is equivalent to:

```
foreach($o[$_product_id]['data'] as $_attr => $_value) {
  echo $_attr;
}
echo $_value;
```

See? You iterate over array, but output only keys, and last value after the end.

And yes, this is **the standard** behaviour of a `foreach` without `{}` -  after `foreach` definition **only one** line runs in a loop. All other lines are considered out of the loop. Yep, that's not like in python).

So the fix is simple - add `{}`:

```
foreach($o[$_product_id]['data'] as $_attr => $_value) {
  echo $_attr;
  echo $_value;
}
```

Comment: incredible. yes! how did I overlook this ... major thanks